# error cannot find symbol - variable

Tags: java, variables, find, symbols

I am new to using Java - so please forgive my ignorance. Would you be able to look at this code and let me know why I get error:

> cannot find symbol - variable

when I call the constructor method. I am using BlueJ. Basically I put in the variables and then hit ok to create an object but it comes up with that error.

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Membership here.
 * 
 * @author (Gohar Warraich) 
 * @version (1.0)
 */

public class Membership
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String phonenumber;
    private int idnumber;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Membership
     */
    public Membership(String newfirstname, String newlastname, String newphonenumber, int newidnumber)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        firstname = newfirstname;
        lastname = newlastname;
        phonenumber = newphonenumber;
        idnumber = newidnumber;

    }

    /**
     * Accessor method of Membership
     */
    public String getfirstname()
    {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getlastname()
    {
        return lastname;
    }

    public String getphonenumber()
    {
        return phonenumber; 
    }

    public int getidnumber()
    {
        return idnumber;
    }

    /**
     * Mutator method of Membership 
     */
    public void setfirstname(String insertfirstname)
    {
        firstname = insertfirstname;
    }

    public void setlastname(String insertlastname)
    {
        lastname = insertlastname;
    }

    public void setphonenumber(String insertphonenumber)
    {
        phonenumber = insertphonenumber;
    }

    public void setid(int insertidnumber)
    {
        idnumber = insertidnumber;
    }

    public void printMembership()
    {
        System.out.println("The firstname is " + firstname + " The lastname is " + lastname +" The phoneNumber is "+ phonenumber +" The idNumber is " +idnumber); 
    }
}
```

Comment: And how are you calling the constructor?

Comment: You need to show the code where you are calling the constructor. That is where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

@gohar, There isn't a problem in this code. It must be in your call to the constructor. I'll give you an example of what this should look like.

```
Membership membershipName = new Membership ("String", "String", "String", 0101)
```

0101 can be any int, and you can name the variable what ever you want by changing membershipName. Hope this helps. :)